# Find key value type in deep nesting from objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There is an array that has few object and each object includes deep nesting, which consists of objects and arrays. Need to find the value type of a specific key. Thank you!

To find out if key value type is object, i've tried to do it using JSON.stringify, but dont think this is a good way